# In Vim, how would I make a change then go back where I was?

Tags: vim

In vim, lots of times, I'm working on something, and I need to jump down a bunch of lines (or up) and make a quick edit. How do I then quickly go back to where I was?

Maybe...

```
`.
```

or...

```
`2
```

Comment: Haven't you posted the answer already?  Mark your position, do your evil deeds then goto the mark?

Comment: Meh, I'd love to have a single command I could remap to. I do this fairly often.

Answer (score 2):

I typically do a `:split`, edit and then `:q`.

It's fast in my setup, because I have the following:

```
nmap <Bar> <C-w>v
nmap - <C-w>s
map <C-c> :quit<CR>
```

So I just have to hit `-`, edit and then Ctrl+c.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried two single quotes? I'm not sure if that is exactly what you are looking for or not, but I use it all the time to say go look at the top of the file for an include or something, then '' to jump back to where I was.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_around

''
Return to the line where the cursor was before the latest jump.
(Two single quotes.)

Comment: The one difference for me is "go look at the top of the file for an include or something **make a tiny change**, then... " go back to where I was.

Comment: As long as your change doesn't include another jump, I "think" it will do what you want.  Give it a try and see how it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply mark your current position with `ma` (using register a as an example), do whatever you need to do and then jump back to the mark with `` `a ``.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this

```
nnoremap t g;zz
vnoremap t g;zz
nnoremap T g,zz
vnoremap T g,zz
```

So t now moves me back one step in the changelist (changelist, right?), and shift + t moves me forward one step.

The zz helps center the line so it's easier to read.